# Unable to get where query working in not in

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

```
DELETE FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT f.id FROM `tblclients` f);
```

I am running the above query to delete invoices where the userid doesn't exist in the client pool.

In theory, each part of this query works individually but when combined "NOT IN" - doesn't work.

I have no idea as to why this is, I have tested it a lot and can't get it to work at all.

When running the below query from tblinvoices:

```
SELECT * FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE userid = 73;
```

The query returns correctly, and returns that user's invoices:

```
SELECT f.id FROM `tblclients` f;
```

Also runs perfectly fine on it's own, returning all the userids from tblclients.

***I AM USING SELECT FOR PREVIEWING CHANGES***

Simulating the query I am able to see this returned:

```
SQL query:

DELETE FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT f.id FROM `tblclients` f)

Matched rows: 0
```

Comment: The query that you complain doesn't delete invoices is a `SELECT` query, not a `DELETE` query...

Comment: @obe Yes I am aware, I am using SELECT to preview the results.

Comment: Then provide the actual query that doesn't work for you...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0?

Comment: It looks ok to me... what actually happens? Just invoices that you expect to be deleted are not deleted? Can you provide the actual data from the tables?

Comment: I have added what is returned upon simulating the query.

Comment: Are you sure there are userid in tblinvoices that don't exist in tblclients?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have added multiple test records plus I know there are invoices with no matching users.

Comment: Then post sample data of both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct .Please check data types of userid in both tables tblinvoices and tblclients,both should be same data type and check the ids available or notavailable tblinvoices

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I found the issue causing this, Maria has a DB setting which doesn't allow NOT IN.

This is normally the case with some Shared Hosting.